# Hiding Series in Chart in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

The following is my code for creating a chart in each worksheet in a workbook. I found this code online and modified it for what I needed. I am a novice at VBA and am not sure how to manipulate code containing `With` statements.

This code was working great until I changed the information located in cell B1, my chart title. Since then, my code has been creating 2 series. Series 2 is not plotted on the graph, but appears in the legend. When I click on the graph to view the data it is collecting, it does not populate, as this image demonstrates

[image]

When I view the series I want to keep, it does show A3:A630 and B3:B630.

How can I delete this Series 2?

Related: I also entered text into A1 and it created Series 3. I want to make sure only Series 1 is visible on my chart.

I have already tried recording the macro for deleting the series and using that in my code, but I always receive

> cannot proceed because of break in code

The recorded macro yielded:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Delete
```

I have also found a way of hiding the series, but once again when I insert it after my `.SeriesCollection` Block it gives the "break in code" error.

```
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
```

Original Code for creating Charts

```
  Sub chartcreation()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As Chart

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

        With chrt
            'Data?
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = sh.Range("B1").Value
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = sh.Range("$A$3:$A$630")
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = sh.Range("$B$3:$B$630")

            'Titles
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = sh.Range("B1").Value
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text =     sh.Range("A2")
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = sh.Range("B2")

            'Formatting
            .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
            .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
            .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 15
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 90
            .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
            .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 60
            .HasLegend = True
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

If the 2 above options of modifying the code are completely wrong, I did find the following code that goes through each chart on each worksheet and deletes the series, but I cannot figure out how to modify it for my needs.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  Dim Sht As Worksheet
  Dim ShtName As String
  Dim R As Range
  Dim ASht As Worksheet

  Set R = ActiveCell        'Save the activecell
  Set ASht = ActiveSheet    'Save the activesheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ShtName = Sht.Name
    Select Case ShtName
      Case "One", "Two", "Three"            'Charts are on multiple sheets
        Call DeleteLegendEntries(Sht)
    End Select
  Next Sht

  ASht.Activate                              'Back to original sheet
  R.Activate                                 'Back to original cell
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

To reiterate: I would like to hide or delete all series except series 1, which I have renamed, in each worksheet in one workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with more research and help from an IT person at work.

I added in the following code before the with chart statement. (Found from Jon Peltier)

```
Do Until chrt.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
chrt.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Loop
```

The whole code looks like

```
Sub chartcreation()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As Chart


For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

Do Until chrt.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
chrt.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Loop

    With chrt
        'Data?
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = sh.Range("B1").Value
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = sh.Range("$A$3:$A$630")
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = sh.Range("$B$3:$B$630")

        'Titles
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = sh.Range("B1").Value
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = sh.Range("A2")
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = sh.Range("B2")

        'Formatting
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 15
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 90
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 60
        .HasLegend = True

    End With
Next
```

End Sub